# error: value cassandraTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, connector

I want to access Cassandra table in Spark. Below are the version that I am using

- spark: spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6
- cassandra: apache-cassandra-2.2.3
- spark cassandra connector: spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10-1.5.0-M2.jar

Below is the script:

```scala
sc.stop

import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test1", "words")
```

when i run the last statement i get an error

> :32: error: value cassandraTable is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext
>          val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test1", "words")

hints to resolve the error would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: For starters connector version should match Spark version so for Spark 1.4 you should use connector 1.4.

Comment: i tried with version spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10-1.4.0.jar. Still the same error

Comment: Are you sure you import statement is not throwing an exception? If not how are you launching the shell? --packages?

Comment: i use hte below command to launch the shell ./bin/spark-shell --jars /opt/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.0.jar

Answer (score 3):

Actually on shell you need to import respective packages. No need to do anything extra.

e.g. scala> import com.datastax.spark.connector._;